# ClassLoader does not find classes when prog. is exported to .jar

Tags: class, jar, export, classloader

so here is the thing:
I have a class that scans dot defined package name (eg. com.this.package) for classes and then adds them to the list. 
Curious is that it works fine when Im working in IDE but when I export project to executable jar file, with all of its needed dependencies, it is unable to find any class.

Code looks like this:

```
private void discoverTestCases(String packageName) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
System.out.println("2");
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread()
            .getContextClassLoader();
    System.out.println("3");
    String path = packageName.replace('.', '/');
    System.out.println("4"+ path);
    Enumeration<URL> resources = classLoader.getResources(path);

    System.out.println("5");
    List<File> dirs = new ArrayList<File>();

    while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
        URL  resource = resources.nextElement();
        System.out.println(resource.getFile());
        System.out.println(resource.getPath());
        dirs.add(new File(resource.getFile()));
    }

    List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();

    for (File directory : dirs) {
        classes.addAll(findClasses(directory, packageName));
    }

getTestableClasses(classes);

}
```

as you can see, I have added some printouts to see where can I get in runtime, but the last I get displayed is '5'.

Can you give me a hand?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

well, the thing is that in this way, ClassLoader tryes to load classes from their absolute path which leads to projects folder where they are located.
But when project is packed in single JAR file this folders do not exist anymore. So solution is to search in JAR file and use UrlClassLoader to load them:

```
File f = new File("file.jar");
    List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();

    URL [] urls = {new URL("jar:"+f.toURL()+"!/")};

    URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

    JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(f);
    Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jarFile.entries();
    String className=null;
    while(e.hasMoreElements()){
        JarEntry je = e.nextElement();

         if(je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")){
             continue;
         }

         className  = je.getName().substring(0,je.getName().length()-6);
         className = className.replace('/', '.');

         if(className.contains("test.smoke") || className.contains("test.ml") || className.contains("test.sanity")){
             System.out.println("classname::: "+className);
             Class c = Class.forName(className);
             classes.add(c);
         }
```